# Can't configure Ebean Play Framework 2.5.x

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I have a problem configuring Ebean for Play Framework 2.5.x. I get the following error when I type sbt run:

> Play ebean module has been replaced with an external Play ebean plugin.
>   See https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24 for details.

I have added javaJdbc as a Dependency and in my build.sbt I also have:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
```

In application.conf:

```
ebean.default = ["models.*"]
```

And plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "3.0.0")
```

Any idea on how to fix this? https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24 Doesn't give any other information. Thanks!

EDIT
Here's my full build.sbt:

```
name := """chatbot"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)


scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs, 
  javaEbean, 
  evolutions
)


fork in run := true
```

Comment: As stated above I get the following error: 
Play ebean module has been replaced with an external Play ebean plugin.
See https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24 for details.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?

Comment: could you show your build.sbt from top to bottom?

Comment: I'll edit my original question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is said in the migration guide:

> To migrate an existing Play project that uses Ebean to use the new
>   external Ebean plugin, remove javaEbean from your libraryDependencies
>   in build.sbt

That's exactly, that you forgot to do, so in the dependencies section you need to have this:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  evolutions
)
```